# Tracking off-site clicks

Tags: php, google-analytics

When sending an HTML email newsletter I understand how to detect if someone clicks on a URL that goes to my site, but what if I have a URL that goes to another site, is there a way to track if they click that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the URLs for off-site links go via your site first.

How you do this will depend on which server-site language you're using, but for PHP, it could be something as simple as:

```
<?php

    header("Location: " . urldecode($_GET["url"]));

?>
```

With a link such as http://www.example.com/redirect.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Comment: Perfect!  That fixed my issue.  Sorry it took me an extra day to respond, I had to wait for the campaign data to get to Google Analytic.  Thanks for your help.